# How to escape "" using command cat in R?

Tags: json, r, escaping, rstudio

I am creating my own JSON file in R. I can't use any package for JSON because I need my own strict form of JSON.

I need to write some words with "" using CAT , but command CAT use "" too.

Any ideas how to escape this character " ?

I need something like this

> cat(" "auto": "one","two",three" ")

[1] "auto": "one","two",three"

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Here's an example `cat("this is it \" or is it?")`.

Comment: I doubt that you should be using `cat` at all.

Comment: Now my output looks like: \"type\": \"one\",\"two\",\three\" .... but I want to make backslash invisible in output...Any advice?

Comment: I change my code from cat to sink aj it works. Thank you guys for advices :)